# What's the difference between deep and shallow static analysis?

Tags: xcode, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

What's the difference between shallow and deep static analysis? I'm using Xcode at the moment, and noticed that there's a build setting that distinguishes between the two.

I'm curious about this in the general case, and I'm also wondering if there's any difference in how Clang implements this distinction.

I tried some Google-foo and I couldn't find an answer. I tried going through the Apple and Clang docs to see if they explain it but I didn't find anything. Hopefully I didn't miss an obvious stone to overturn in my searching.

[image: Xcode screenshot of the deep & shallow static analysis options]

Comment: Accurate static analysis is a difficult problem - I'm guessing Deep simply means the analyzer works harder (which makes the analysis slower and resource intensive, but there will be more true positives and/or less false negatives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1)
A [talk](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/402xdx2x3ccrfzk85j9dysimvsui/402/402.pdf?dl=1) from apple's Evan Cheng (compilation tech) gives an indication (see pages 157/158):

- shallow - quick analysis
- deep - more thorough analysis

Recommendation: `Always analyze in deep mode as part of qualifications`

(2) 
Some more details you can find in the source code of the [analyzerOptions](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/AnalyzerOptions_8h_source.html)
There is the UserModeKind variable:

```
00184   /// \brief Describes the kinds for high-level analyzer mode.
00185   enum UserModeKind {
00186     UMK_NotSet = 0,
00187     /// Perform shallow but fast analyzes.
00188     UMK_Shallow = 1,
00189     /// Perform deep analyzes.
00190     UMK_Deep = 2
00191   };
00192 
00193   /// Controls the high-level analyzer mode, which influences the default 
00194   /// settings for some of the lower-level config options (such as IPAMode).
00195   /// \sa getUserMode
00196   UserModeKind UserMode;
00197 
00198   /// Controls the mode of inter-procedural analysis.
00199   IPAKind IPAMode;
```

Without looking too deep into the code you see that one difference is the deactivation of the (timeconsuming) inter-procedural analysis...

Comment: Can you provide any other differences?